# Transposing a matrix using class members instead of vector of vectors

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix, vector

I've been working on a vector and matrix class where i need to create class functions to do stuff like multiplication, addition and so on. My matrix is always going to be a 3x3!

My vector class is the following:

```
class MVector {
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, MVector &obj);


public:
    // default constructor  Vector ve; XXX double check if the : lingo is to be done here or in definition
    MVector() : x(0), y(0), z(0) {};

    MVector(double x, double y, double z);

    double getX() const;

    double getY() const;

    double getZ() const;

    void setX(float x);

    void setY(float y);

    void setZ(float z);

    ~MVector();

    MVector operator+(const MVector &obj) const;

    MVector operator-(const MVector &obj) const;

    MVector operator*(const MVector &obj) const;

    double getModulus() const;

private:
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
};
```

and my Matrix class is the following:

```
class Matrix {
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, Matrix &obj);

public:
    Matrix(const MVector &v1, const MVector &v2, const MVector &v3);

    Matrix() : mat3x3(3, MVector()) {};

    Matrix operator+(Matrix const &obj) const;

    Matrix operator-(Matrix const &obj) const;

    Matrix operator*(Matrix const &obj) const;

    MVector operator*(MVector const &obj) const;

    Matrix operator*(double const &scalar) const;

    Matrix transponse() const;

    double det() const;

    ~Matrix();

private:
    std::vector<MVector> mat3x3;
};
```

The current issue i am facing is producing a function to transpose a matrix without using brute force substitution. If i had a vector of vectors, the following would work but I need to develop something that can be used with the classes above.

```
for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i) {
      for (int j = 0; j < column; ++j) {
         transpose[j][i] = a[i][j];
      }
}
```

Any suggestions would help!

This is what I have so far but its not much:

```
Matrix Matrix::transponse() const {
    Matrix result;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
            if (i == 0 && j == 0) result.mat3x3[j].setX(mat3x3[i].getX());
            else if (i == 1 && j == 1) result.mat3x3[j].setY(mat3x3[i].getY());
            else if (i == 2 && j == 2) result.mat3x3[j].setZ(mat3x3[i].getZ());

        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Off-topic suggestion : Either mark those destructors as `= default;` or do not declare them.

Comment: You have to avoid the loops: `transpose[0].x = a[0].x; transpose[0].y = a[1].x; transpose[0].z = a[2].x;
transpose[1].x = a[0].y; transpose[1].y = a[1].y; transpose[1].z = a[2].y;
transpose[2].x = a[0].z; transpose[2].y = a[1].z; transpose[2].z = a[2].z;`

Comment: Why not to have double mat3x3[9] or std::array<9,double> mat3x3 member instead of that vector? Then transpose is just 9 assignments result.mat3x3[0] = mat3x3[0]; result.mat3x3[1] = mat3x3[3]; result.mat3x3[2] = mat3x3[6]; result.mat3x3[3] = mat3x3[1]; etc.

Comment: your title is a little confusing, because whether you use `std::vector` and/or members of a class are orthogonal issues.